# tags Doxygen vs Intellisense Eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, intellisense, doxygen

I use Eclipse (Mars2) Doxygen, Eclox and PDT.
I comment some code:

```
 /**
 * @fn __construct($a, $b)
 * @brief Constructeur de l'objet XXXX
 * @details blablabla
 * @param Boolean $a blablabla
 * @param Boolean $b blablabla
 */
```

It's ok in Doxygen, but in Eclipse Intellisense I see @fn, @brief, @details.

Which tags must I use to work on Doxygen and Eclipse Intellisense?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

PDT doesn't support doxygen.

It's support standard PHPDoc tags like:
@param / @return / @method / @deprecated.

You can open enhancement request for doxygen: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=PDT